# r "slot" two columns into one (like a zip)

Tags: r, merge

Given two columns (perhaps from a data frame) of equal length *N*, how can I produce a column of length *2N* with the odd entries from the first column and the even entries from the second column?

Suppose I have the following data frame

```
df.1 <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[1:10], Y = 2*(1:10)-1, Z = 2*(1:10))
```

How can I produce this data frame `df.2`?

```
i <- 1
j <- 0
XX <- NA
while (i <= 10){
XX[i+j] <- LETTERS[i]
XX[i+j+1]<- LETTERS[i]
i <- i+1
j <- i-1
}

df.2 <- data.frame(X.X = XX, Y.Z = c(1:20))
```

Comment: [**Here's another way**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16443987/559784) you may be interested.

Comment: you can extend it to multiple vectors by having them in a list and doing: `unlist(ll)[order(sequence(vapply(ll, length, 0L)))]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ggplot2` has an unexported function `interleave` which does this.

Whilst unexported it *does* have a help page (`?ggplot2:::interleave`)

```
with(df.1, ggplot2:::interleave(Y,Z))
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Interesting. I wrote my own interleave, not realizing there's already one sitting in a widely-used package.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. Easily extensible to multiple vectors too!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want to create a new vector twice the length of the vectors X, Y and Z in your data frame and then want all the elements of X to occupy the odd indices of this new vector and all the elements of Y the even indices. If so, then the code below should do the trick:

```
foo<-vector(length=2*nrow(df.1), mode='character')

foo[seq(from = 1, to = 2*length(df.1$X), by=2)]<-as.character(df.1$X)
foo[seq(from = 2, to = 2*length(df.1$X), by=2)]<-df.1$Y
```

Note, I first create an empty vector foo of length 20, then fill it in with elements of df.1$X and df.1$Y.

Cheers,

Danny

Comment: This is a narrow second to the `ggplot2:::interleave()` solution. Yours seems safer but just a bit longer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` from `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
foo <- melt(df.1, id.vars='X')

> foo
   X variable value
1  A        Y     1
2  B        Y     3
3  C        Y     5
4  D        Y     7
5  E        Y     9
6  F        Y    11
7  G        Y    13
8  H        Y    15
9  I        Y    17
10 J        Y    19
11 A        Z     2
12 B        Z     4
13 C        Z     6
14 D        Z     8
15 E        Z    10
16 F        Z    12
17 G        Z    14
18 H        Z    16
19 I        Z    18
20 J        Z    20
```

Then you can sort and pick the columns you want:

```
foo[order(foo$X), c('X', 'value')]
```

Comment: Good solution for my example but it may be the case that ordering `X` gives the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using base R.

First index the character vector of the data.frame using the vector `[1,1,2,2 ... 10,10]` and store as `X.X`.  Next, `rbind` the data.frame vectors `Y` & `Z` effectively "zipping" them and store in `Y.X`.

```
> res <- data.frame(
+   X.X = df.1$X[c(rbind(1:10, 1:10))],
+   Y.Z = c(rbind(df.1$Y, df.1$Z))
+ )
> head(res)
  X.X Y.Z
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   B   3
4   B   4
5   C   5
6   C   6
```

Comment: You could also replace the `X.X` line with `rep(df.1$X,each=2)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to R myself and find the best way to learn is to answer beginner Qs on SO. Great tip!

Answer (score 1):

A <strike>one</strike> two liner in base R:

```
test <- data.frame(X.X=df.1$X,Y.Z=unlist(df.1[c("Y","Z")]))
test[order(test$X.X),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want what you asked for in the first paragraph, and the rest of what you posted is your attempt at solving it.

```
a=df.1[df.1$Y%%2>0,1:2]
b=df.1[df.1$Z%%2==0,c(1,3)]
names(a)=c("X.X","Y.Z")
names(b)=names(a)
df.2=rbind(a, b)
```

If you want to group them by X.X as shown in your example, you can do:

```
library(plyr)
arrange(df.2, X.X)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry my example is misleading. It's meant to be a specific instance of the general problem and the corresponding solution. For illustrative purposes.

Comment: Got it. Judging by what you selected as your response, you were also just looking for the odd- vs. even-index split. I interpreted your question as looking for the odd- vs. even-VALUE split ....