# R: insert elements into vector (a variation)

Tags: r

I have the vector:

```
x = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I would like to make it:

```
x = 1,2,3,0,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,7
```

inserting the element 0 into `x` at the proper positions `ind`. I happen to know that

```
ind = 4,5,6,10,11
```

In the problem, `ind` is specified as the position of each inserted 0 in the new version of `x`. This is a toy problem. In reality `x` and `ind` are 1000s of elements long, and memory is very tight.
I have seen some threads that seem related but they do not solve the problem. Given `ind`, they would create

```
 x = 1 2 3 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 0
```

which is wrong (it misinterprets the insertion points).

- [How to insert elements into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector)
- [insert elements in a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951248/insert-elements-in-a-vector-in-r?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be

```
v1 <- numeric(length(x)+length(ind))
v1[setdiff(seq_along(v1), ind)]  <- x
v1
#[1] 1 2 3 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 7
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:7
ind <- c(4:6,10:11)
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. It would be great to have an in-place solution, i.e. just using x instead of creating a new variable. The reason is that memory is very tight. x is huge