# R insert element how to insert element into vector

Tags: r, vector, insert

Insert 16 as the 3rd element into the sales vector
the sales vector is

```
Sales <- c (8,11,14,20,21,11,18,10,6,22)
```

how can I insert 16 as the 3rd element into the sales vector?

Comment: Try: `Sales[3]<-16`

Comment: Maybe take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951248/insert-elements-in-a-vector-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951248/insert-elements-in-a-vector-in-r

Comment: When you say insert 16 as the third element, do you mean replacing the current third element (output has same length) or adding 16 in front of 14 and having an output length + 1?

Answer (score 1):

```
sales <- c(sales[1:2], 16, sales[3:length(sales)])
```

or

```
index <- 3
number <- 16
sales <- c(sales[1:(index - 1)], number, sales[index:length(sales)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you add a bit of explanation for future visitors?