# how to alternatively concatenate 3 strings

Tags: string, r, concatenation

I have 3 strings:

```
a<-c("a1","a2","a3")
b<-c("b1","b2","b3")
c<-c("c1","c2","c3")
```

How can I get the following output:

```
"a1","b1","c1","a2","b2","c2","a3","b3","c3"
```

Here is what I tried:

```
paste(a,b,c,sep='","')
```

And what I got:

`[1] "a1\",\"b1\",\"c1" "a2\",\"b2\",\"c2" "a3\",\"b3\",\"c3"`

Is there a way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Will this work: `paste(letters[1:3], rep(1:3,each=3), sep='')` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use

```
c(rbind(a,b,c))
```

which (`rbind`) puts the three variables together into a matrix (row-wise), and then (`c()`) converts them back into a vector, taking advantage of the fact that R stores matrices in column-wise order.

Some of the diversity of the answers to this question stems (I think) from a lack of clarity on the OP's part (don't know whether this is an issue of understanding or communication ...) between combining individual character strings (e.g. `paste("a","b")` results in a vector of length 1: `"a b")`) and combining *vectors* of character strings (`c("a","b")` results in a vector of length 2: `"a" "b"`)

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way:

```
interleave <- function(...) {
    ll <- list(...)
    unlist(ll)[order(unlist(lapply(ll, seq_along)))]
}
interleave(a,b,c)
# [1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "a2" "b2" "c2" "a3" "b3" "c3"
```

The advantage is that you don't have to depend on the vectors having the same size. For example:

```
a <- paste("a", 1:3, sep="")
b <- paste("b", 1:4, sep="")
c <- paste("c", 1:5, sep="")

interleave(a,b,c)
# [1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "a2" "b2" "c2" "a3" "b3" "c3" "b4" "c4" "c5"
```

This is closely related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443987/559784).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work:

```
a<-c("a1","a2","a3")
b<-c("b1","b2","b3")
c<-c("c1","c2","c3")

c(sapply(seq(1,3), function(x) c(a[x],b[x],c[x])))

[1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "a2" "b2" "c2" "a3" "b3" "c3"
```

Comment: @BenBolker Some of my answers are so amazingly inefficient, they are down right silly in retrospect.  But that is why I am here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` to put them in the order you want

```
> x <- c(a, b, c)
> x[sapply(1:3, grep, x)]
# [1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "a2" "b2" "c2" "a3" "b3" "c3"
```

or `unlist(strsplit(paste(a, b, c), " "))` would work too.

Although, it seems like you may be trying to paste commas in there.  If that's what you're shooting for, try using `cat` with the `sep` argument set to `","`

```
> cat(x[sapply(1:3, grep, x)], sep = ",")
# a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3
```

or perhaps `paste`, but with both the `sep` and `collapse` arguments set to `","`

```
> paste(a, b, c, sep = ",", collapse = ",")
# [1] "a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
paste('\"', paste(a,b,c,sep='\",\"'), '\"', collapse='\",\"')
```

You don't need double quotes to get the ",". The inner `paste()` does what you tried then the outer `paste()` joins these all together to give you the output you want. Don't worry about the output having "\" in it - if you print it out with `cat`, you'll see them disappear.

Does that work for you?

Comment: I think the OP is after a vector of length 9 (for the given example).