# Inserting values in one list into another list by index

Tags: r

I have two lists `x` and `y`, and a vector of indices `where`.

```
x <- list(a = 1:4, b = letters[1:6])
y <- list(a = c(20, 50), b = c("abc", "xyz"))
where <- c(2, 4)
```

I want to insert `y` into `x` at the indices in `where`, so that the result is

```
list(a = c(1,20,2,50,3,4), b = c("a", "abc", "b", "xyz", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
#$a
#[1]  1 20  2 50  3  4
#
#$b
#[1] "a"   "abc" "b"   "xyz" "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"
```

I've been trying it with `append`, but it's not working.

```
lapply(seq(x), function(i) append(x[[i]], y[[i]], after = where[i]))
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  2 20 50  3  4
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "abc" "xyz" "e"   "f"
```

This is appending at the wrong index.  Plus, I want to retain the list names in the process. I also don't know if `append` is the right function for this, since I've literally never seen it used anywhere.

**What's the best way to insert values from one list into another list using an index vector?**

Comment: I don't understand your output. Should the data from 'y' replace data from 'x' or be inserted at those indeces but keep all of 'x'? In  your given output, in `$b` the letter `b` was replaced but the letter `d` was not, and you had a similar thing in `$a`. Can you clarify?

Comment: Inserted.  It says that in the question. :)

Comment: i reckon this [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16443260/471093)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an `mapply` solution

```
x <- list(a = 1:4, b = letters[1:6])
y <- list(a = c(20, 50), b = c("abc", "xyz"))
where <- c(2, 4)

mapply(function(x,y,w) {
    r <- vector(class(x), length(x)+length(y))
    r[-w] <- x
    r[w] <- y
    r
}, x, y, MoreArgs=list(where), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

which returns

```
$a
[1]  1 20  2 50  3  4

$b
[1] "a"   "abc" "b"   "xyz" "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"
```

which seems to be the results you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Here I created a `APPEND` function that is an iterative (via `Reduce`) version of `append`:

```
APPEND <- function(x, where, y)
   Reduce(function(z, args)do.call(append, c(list(z), args)),
          Map(list, y, where - 1), init = x)
```

Then you just need to call that function via `Map`:

```
Map(APPEND, x, list(where), y)
```

Comment: `do.call` interests me, but I don't quite understand what's happening.  In `Reduce`, what is `z`?

Comment: Granted, it is not straight forward but play a bit with `Reduce` and you will probably get it. `Reduce(f, y, x)` starts from `x` and replaces it iteratively like this: `x <- f(x, y[1]); x <- f(x, y[2]); x <- f(x, y[3]);` etc. For `f` I could not use `append` directly because it uses three arguments, so I had to rely on `do.call` to create a function that only takes two arguments: `function(z, args)`.