# How to merge 2 vectors alternating indexes?

Tags: r, vector, merge

I would like to merge 2 vectors this way :

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(11,12,13)
merged vector : c(1,11,2,12,3,13)
```

How could I do it ?

Comment: Some approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443260/interleave-lists-in-r)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

This will work using `rbind` :

```
c(rbind(a, b))
```

For example:

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(11,12,13)

c(rbind(a,b))

#[1]  1 11  2 12  3 13
```

##### Explanation

This works because R stores arrays in [column-major order](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html?q=major#:%7E:text=Because%20both%20matrices%20and%20arrays%20are%20just%20vectors%20with%20special%20attributes%2C%20you%20can%20subset%20them%20with%20a%20single%20vector%2C%20as%20if%20they%20were%20a%201D%20vector.%20Note%20that%20arrays%20in%20R%20are%20stored%20in%20column%2Dmajor%20order%3A).

When you `rbind()` the two vectors, you get:

```
rbind_result <- rbind(a, b)
rbind_result
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# a    1    2    3
# b   11   12   13
```

Then `c()` coerces `rbind_result` into a column-wise flattened vector:

```
merged <- c(rbind_result)
merged
# [1] 1 11 2 12 3 13
```

Comment: This solution would not work for vector that differ in length, solution by @RichardScriven is more robust for such situations (if `length(a)` is greater than `lenght(b)` or `max` of lengths is used for indexing).

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you. It would be great if you could add a brief explanation as to why it works as it is not immediately obvious why row binding 2 vectors and then concatenating the resulting vectors would produce the interspersed result. I am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: One of the side-effects of the function `c` is that is turns data structures into vectors. So using `c` here is akin to doing `as.vector(rbind(a,b))`

Comment: @ColorStatistics I added an edit to explain the intuition for this solution. `rbind()` does a row-wise combination of the two vectors into a matrix. Then `c()` converts the matrix into an atomic vector in column-wise order.

Comment: Wonderful!  as.vector() also works fine.

Answer (score 29):

The `rbind()` answer by @jalapic is excellent.  Here's an alternative that creates a new vector then assigns the alternating values to it.

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(11,12,13)

x <- vector(class(a), length(c(a, b)))
x[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- a
x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- b
x
# [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13
```

And one more that shows `append`

```
c(sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) append(a[i], b[i], i)))
# [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13
```

Comment: I love your answer to this question (though in the append example, when I have one vector with 2-items, and another with 3-items, I end up with a final vector with an NA at the end). I went with the first option, but don't quite understand what is going on in these lines:

x[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- a
x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- b

Can you explain at all?

Comment: @PatrickWilliams - `c(TRUE, FALSE)`, when used to index, means to take every other value starting with the **first**. `c(TRUE, FALSE)` is recycled through the entire length of the vector (so it's like saying "yes, no, yes, no, yes, no" in this example).  On the other hand `c(FALSE TRUE)` takes every other value starting with the **second** in the same manner.

Comment: `c(sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) c(a[i], b[i])))` seems to work

Answer (score 17):

Just wanted to add a simpler solution that works for when vectors are unequal length and you want to append the extra data to the end.

```
> a <- 1:3
> b <- 11:17
> c(a, b)[order(c(seq_along(a)*2 - 1, seq_along(b)*2))]
 [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13 14 15 16 17
```

Explanation:

- `c(a, b)` creates a vector of the values in `a` and `b`.
- `seq_along(a)*2 - 1` creates a vector of the first `length(a)` odd numbers.
- `seq_along(b)*2` creates a vector of the first `length(b)` even numbers.
- `order(...)` will return the indexes of the numbers in the two `seq_along` vectors such that `x[order(x)]` is an ordered list.  Since the first `seq_along` contains the even numbers and the second `seq_along` has the odds, order will take the first element from the first `seq_along`, then the first elements of the second `seq_along`, then the second element from the first `seq_along`, etc. interspersing the two vector indexes and leaving the extra data at the tail.
- By indexing `c(a, b)` using the `order` vector, we will intersperse `a` and `b`.

As a note, since `seq_along` returns `numeric(0)` when the input is `NULL` this solution works even if one of the vectors is length `0`.

Comment: Just `c(a,b)[order(c(seq_along(a),seq_along(b)))]` should do it I think. No need for the odd/even calculations.

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve a similar problem, but my vectors were of unequal length.  And, I didn't want to recycle the shorter vector, but just append the tail of the longer vector.

And the solution for @RichardScriven didn't work for me (though I may have done something wrong and didn't try hard to troubleshoot).

Here is my solution:

```
#' Riffle-merges two vectors, possibly of different lengths
#'
#' Takes two vectors and interleaves the elements.  If one vector is longer than
#' the other, it appends on the tail of the longer vector to the output vector.
#' @param a First vector
#' @param b Second vector
#' @return Interleaved vector as described above.
#' @author Matt Pettis
riffle <- function(a, b) {
  len_a <- length(a)
  len_b <- length(b)
  len_comm <- pmin(len_a, len_b)
  len_tail <- abs(len_a - len_b)

  if (len_a < 1) stop("First vector has length less than 1")
  if (len_b < 1) stop("Second vector has length less than 1")

  riffle_common <- c(rbind(a[1:len_comm], b[1:len_comm]))

  if (len_tail == 0) return(riffle_common)

  if (len_a > len_b) {
    return(c(riffle_common, a[(len_comm + 1):len_a]))
  } else {
    return(c(riffle_common, b[(len_comm + 1):len_b]))
  }
}

# Try it out
riffle(1:7, 11:13)
  [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4  5  6  7

riffle(1:3, 11:17)
   [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13 14 15 16 17
```

HTH,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach is `vctrs::vec_interleave`:

```r
vctrs::vec_interleave(a, b)
#[1]  1 11  2 12  3 13
```

Answer (score 1):

@MBo's answer to my question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773002/2556061 implies a solution for evenly interlacing vectors of unequal length. I'm reporting it here in for reference.

```
interleave <- function(x, y)
{
  m <- length(x)
  n <- length(y)
  xi <- yi <- 1
  len <- m + n
  err <- len %/% 2
  res <- vector()
  for (i in 1:len)
  {
    err <- err - m
    if (err < 0)
    {

      res[i] <- x[xi]
      xi <- xi + 1
      err <- err + len
    } else
    {
       res[i] <- y[yi]
      yi <- yi + 1
     }
  }
  res
}
```

gives

```
interleave(1:10, 100:120)

c(100, 1, 101, 102, 2, 103, 104, 3, 105, 106, 4, 107, 108, 5, 109, 110, 111, 6, 112, 113, 7, 114, 115, 8, 116, 117, 9, 118, 119, 10, 120)
```