# Order dataframe by colnames

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I have a dataframe like this :

```
           G2_ref G10_ref G12_ref G2_alt G10_alt G12_alt
20011953      3      6      0      5       1     5    
12677336      0      0      0      1       3     6  
20076754      0      3      0     12      16     8 
2089670       0      4      0      1      11     9
9456633       0      2      0      3      10     0 
468487        0      0      0      0       0     0
```

And I'm trying to sort the columns to have finally this column order :

```
G2_ref G2_alt G10_ref G10_alt G12_ref G12_alt
```

I tried : `df[,order(colnames(df))]`

But I had this order :

```
G10_alt G10_ref G12_alt G12_ref G2_alt G2_ref
```

If anyone had any idea it will be great.

Comment: How was this dataframe created? Perhaps, by `dcast()` or `gather()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to extract the numeric part and also the substring at the end and then do the `order`

```
df[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", names(df))), 
            factor(sub(".*_", "", names(df)), levels = c('ref', 'alt')))]
#          G2_ref G2_alt G10_ref G10_alt G12_ref G12_alt
#20011953      3      5       6       1       0       5
#12677336      0      1       0       3       0       6
#20076754      0     12       3      16       0       8
#2089670       0      1       4      11       0       9
#9456633       0      3       2      10       0       0
#468487        0      0       0       0       0       0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(G2_ref = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G10_ref = c(6L, 
0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L), G12_ref = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G2_alt = c(5L, 
1L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 0L), G10_alt = c(1L, 3L, 16L, 11L, 10L, 0L), 
    G12_alt = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("G2_ref", 
"G10_ref", "G12_ref", "G2_alt", "G10_alt", "G12_alt"), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c("20011953", 
"12677336", "20076754", "2089670", "9456633", "468487"))
```

Comment: This is what it returns me when I write your command line :

`head(rc[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", names(rc))),factor(sub(".*_", "", names(rc)), levels = c('ref', 'alt')))])` 

`integer(0)`

Comment: @Erika I am assuming your dataset as `data.frame` (updated the dataset I used).  If it is a matrix, then use comma, i,.e `rc[, order(...`

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing your data is from genetics and looks pretty standard, first columns with **ref** alleles for all variants then followed by **alt** alleles for all variants.

Meaning we could just use [alternated column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961897/how-to-merge-2-vectors-alternating-indexes) from half way of your *dataframe*, i.e.: we will try to create this index - `c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)` then subset:

```
ix <- c(rbind(seq(1, ncol(df1)/2), seq(ncol(df1)/2 + 1, ncol(df1))))
ix
# [1] 1 4 2 5 3 6

df1[, ix]
#          G2_ref G2_alt G10_ref G10_alt G12_ref G12_alt
# 20011953      3      5       6       1       0       5
# 12677336      0      1       0       3       0       6
# 20076754      0     12       3      16       0       8
# 2089670       0      1       4      11       0       9
# 9456633       0      3       2      10       0       0
# 468487        0      0       0       0       0       0

# or all in one line
df1[, c(rbind(seq(1, ncol(df1)/2), seq(ncol(df1)/2 + 1, ncol(df1))))]
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
      select(G2_ref, G2_alt, G10_ref, G10_alt, G12_ref, G12_alt)
```

Perhaps this is less (complicated) code than @akrun's answer, but only  really suitable for when you want to order a small number of columns.

Comment: Thank you, but actually it's a small example, I can have more than 100 columns

Comment: If you are looking for more compact and much less complicated then `df[c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)]`  and for this you don't need a package

Comment: Fair enough, but there is something to be said for working with column names rather than column numbers, especially in terms of reducing error sources. I agree your answer is the better way to go, though.