# generating random vector in r with particular sum

Tags: r, sample

My aim is to create a vector, with sum 0, in which there are the same number of entries -x and the same number of entry equals x, the length of the vector is even, so it sums up to 0.
I created a function, that has x as an input.
there i insert a sample of the vectorlength but i the end it doesn't work out.

```
vector<-function(x){ 
    for(i in length(sample)){
      if(i %% 2!=0){
     output[sample[i]]<-(-x)
   }
    if(i %% 2 ==0){
      output[sample[i]]<-x
    }
  }
return(output)
  }
```

Comment: please add your expected input and output to your question.

Comment: expected input: any natural number

Comment: expected output:
a vektor of length sample with sum 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vector <- function(x, sample){
  c(rep(x, sample/2), rep(-x, sample/2))
}
print(vector(x = 1, sample = 4))
# [1]  1  1 -1 -1
```

#### Edit

If alterning is required:

```
vector <- function(x, sample){
    c(rbind(rep(-x, sample/2), rep(x, sample/2)))
}
print(vector(x = 1, sample = 4))
# [1] -1  1 -1  1
```

Comment: why this `rbind`?

Comment: To alternate x and -x, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25961969/7224320

Comment: why alternating? Is it required here?

Comment: In the example function it seems like it is trying to alternate, although it may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
foo <- function(x, sample){
  a <- sample(sample, x/2, replace = T)
  c(a,-a)
  # or alternating
  # c(rbind(a,-a))
}
set.seed(123)
foo(4, 1:10)
[1]  3  8 -3 -8
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the title you are looking for a **random** vector. In that case you can simply first generate an ordered vector with the desired properties and then use `sample` to shuffle it:

```
f <- function(x, size){
  sample(c(rep(x, size/2), rep(-x, size/2), if(size %% 2 != 0) 0))
}
f(x = 1, size = 6)
#> [1]  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1
f(x = 1, size = 7)
#> [1]  0 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1
```

**Edit:** Now the function even allows for an odd size.

Comment: that looks simple and sweet
but what to do with size odd?

Comment: @Kasimir You wrote "length of the vector is even", but see the edit ...