# Create boolean vector of length n with k true values well dispersed

Tags: math, sequence

The problem is to create boolean vector of length `n` with `k` `true` entries (and `n-k` `false` entries) well dispersed in the vector.

If `k = 5` and `n = 8` manually created solutions are `[1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1]` or `[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]` etc.

An example for a vector with entries that are not well dispersed would be `[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]`.

A possible criterium for "well-dispersedness" is having alternating blocks of zeros and ones of roughly the same length - specifically with one-blocks of size `floor(n/k)` or `floor(n/k) + 1` and zero-blocks of size `floor(n/(n-k))` or `floor(n/(n-k)) + 1`.

How to create such a vector?

Comment: *A possible criterion ...* There are many possible criteria, you must specify one and also explain what difficulty you're having with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the simplest implementation of [Bresenham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm), and simulate drawing of line segment with end coordinates `(0,0)-(ones,zeros)`. This is just error-propagation approach.

When algorithm generates change of X-coordinate (X-step), it corresponds to 1-entry, Y-step corresponds to zero bit.

```
def Distribute(ones, zeros):
    leng = ones + zeros
    err = leng // 2
    res = []
    for i in range(0, leng):
        err = err - ones
        if err < 0 :
            res.append(1)
            err = err + leng
        else:
            res.append(0)
    print(res)

Distribute(5,3)
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: That is nice! Is this version of Bresenham's algorithm guaranteed to create a vector with exact `k` number of ones or do I need to check the result?

Comment: From this an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774185/2556061 can be derived

Comment: @mschauer I hope  - yes, [random tests passed](https://ideone.com/Ka5kb1). But it is possible to use another implementation with explicit loop by X