# tidy functional way of interweaving rows of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming, purrr

I have written the code below to take two dataframes and interweave them by row based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774185/12447825) example. I believe this is using Bresenham's line algorithm which evenly disperses the shorter dataframe within the longer one.

```
interleave_rows <- function(x, y) {
  m <- nrow(x)
  
  yi <- 1
  len <- m + nrow(y)
  err <- len %/% 2
  res <- x
  
  for (i in 1:len) {
    err <- err - m
    if (err < 0) { err <- err + len } else {
      res <- add_row(res, !!! slice(y, yi), .before = i)
      yi <- yi + 1
    }
  }
  res
}

l <- list(
  a = tibble(n = 1:3, l = letters[1:3]),
  b = tibble(n = 4:9, l = letters[4:9]),
  c = tibble(n = 10:11, l = letters[10:11])
)

reduce(l, interleave_rows)
```

I'm using this in a shiny app as part of a reduce and it's a little slow. I also don't find this to be a very tidy or functional approach to solving this problem. I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to do this without the loop and reassigning variables but I suspect doing so would be faster. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with your function is that it inserts one row at a time to the data frame. It would be better to create interleaving indices, call `rbind` once, and subset by the indexes.

This function works by effectively calculating the quantile of the row number within each data frame, then finding the order of the quantiles:

```r
interleave_rows <- function(df_a, df_b)
{
  if(nrow(df_b) > nrow(df_a)) return(interleave_rows(df_b, df_a))
  a <- seq(nrow(df_a))
  b <- seq(nrow(df_b))
  
  rbind(df_a, df_b)[order(c(a, length(a) * b/(length(b) + 1))), ]
}
```

You can see how this works clearly with these two data frames:

```r
df_a <- data.frame(came_from = rep("A", 10), value = 1:10)
df_b <- data.frame(came_from = rep("B", 4),  value = 101:104)

interleave_rows(df_a, df_b)
#>    came_from value
#> 1          A     1
#> 2          A     2
#> 11         B   101
#> 3          A     3
#> 4          A     4
#> 12         B   102
#> 5          A     5
#> 6          A     6
#> 13         B   103
#> 7          A     7
#> 8          A     8
#> 14         B   104
#> 9          A     9
#> 10         A    10
```

And on your own data you would get:

```
l <- list(
  a = tibble(n = 1:3, l = letters[1:3]),
  b = tibble(n = 4:9, l = letters[4:9]),
  c = tibble(n = 10:11, l = letters[10:11])
)

reduce(l, interleave_rows)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>        n l    
#>    <int> <chr>
#>  1     4 d    
#>  2     1 a    
#>  3     5 e    
#>  4    10 j    
#>  5     6 f    
#>  6     2 b    
#>  7     7 g    
#>  8    11 k    
#>  9     3 c    
#> 10     8 h    
#> 11     9 i
```

In terms of timing, even on small data frames this is over 10 times faster than the original. I suspect the difference would be more marked on larger data frames:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(reduce(l, interleave_rows), 
                               reduce(l, interleave_rows_OP))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                           expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max
#>     reduce(l, interleave_rows)  2.6741  2.94680  3.610404  3.05115  3.22800 21.5097
#>  reduce(l, interleave_rows_OP) 36.2170 37.82645 40.005754 38.90145 40.03415 57.3965
#>  neval
#>    100
#>    100
```

Answer (score 0):

From Allan Cameron's excellent answer I was able to do exactly what I wanted. I'm adding this answer just for reference on how to do this using tidy.

```
interleave_rows_tidy <- function(df_a, df_b) {
  if(nrow(df_b) > nrow(df_a)) return(interleave_rows_tidy(df_b, df_a))
  a <- df_a %>% nrow %>% seq
  b <- df_b %>% nrow %>% seq
  
  bind_rows(df_a, df_b) %>% arrange(c(a, length(a) * b/(length(b) + 1)))
}
```

The key feature for me was how to calculate the sequence. In case anyone is wondering here is the microbenchmarks.

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(reduce(l, interleave_rows_tidy), reduce(l, interleave_rows_SO))
Unit: microseconds
                            expr     min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
 reduce(l, interleave_rows_tidy) 852.904 1088.5170 2586.924 1742.8185 4013.212 7401.947   100
   reduce(l, interleave_rows_SO) 504.500  636.9975 1251.016  769.7465 1357.512 4738.728   100
```

It looks like the tidy version is a little slower on this test data. Both of these are much faster than my original loop that added the rows one-by-one.