# Missing lines ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

Using the packages ggplot2, dplyr and scales, I make the code the following plot

```
grafico_4 <- ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Grafico variado") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='white')) +
  theme( axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("uno", "", "tres", "", "cinco", "", "siete", "", "nueve", "")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, linetype = "dotted") +
  ylab("")
```

[image]

But why do I get a line between "uno" and "dos" and not between "cinco" and "siete", "siete" and "nueve", and after "nueve"? How do I get the lines to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing are not limits; they are x-axis labels. If you encode the limits and labels as such, you get the expected output.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Grafico variado") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='white')) +
  theme( axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = factor(1:10),
    labels = c("uno", "", "tres", "", "cinco", "", "siete", "", "nueve", "")
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, linetype = "dotted") +
  ylab("")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The limits argument of `scale_x_discrete` is a place to put possible values of the scale. But it can't show the same value more than once.

So the hackiest possible solution I could think of would be to use different blank strings:

```
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("uno", "", "tres", " ", "cinco", "   ", "siete", "    ", "nueve")) +
```

This is a terrible solution but I felt compelled to share.

[image]

EDIT: Here's a different approach that I think relies on (in my opinion) more typical ggplot2 syntax. One issue I didn't expect is that ggplot2 doesn't seem to want to print the x axis, even if its breaks and limits are specified, until there is a geom that exists in "x-space" -- ie geom_hline won't trigger it, but in this case an invisible point with an x value will.

I think it's more natural to use continuous axes here. In this case I make the labels for the x axis alternate between the text values and blanks using a trick I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25961969/6851825
It turns `c("uno", "tres")` into `c("uno", "", "tres", "")`.

```
nums <- c("uno", "tres", "cinco", "siete", "nueve")
ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Grafico variado") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:10, name = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, name = NULL,
                     labels = c(rbind(nums, ""))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,11), ylim = c(0,10), expand = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, linetype = "dotted") +
  annotate("point", x = 5, y = 0, alpha = 0)
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the first solution. Works for my purposes. Now, I get a "object 'nums' not found". What am I missing?

Comment: Oops, looks like I forgot to paste that line in. Added above.