# Replace/Merge operations in vectors using CUDA Thrust

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

I have two operations for manipulating elements in device vectors using CUDA Thrust. Which methods can implement these two functions more efficiently?

1. Replace part of values of a vector in batch with the values from another vector. Example is shown below:

   ```
   arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
   arr2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
   // After replacing {4, 5, 6} and {10, 11, 12} in batch = 3:
   arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9, 2, 2, 2]
   ```

   In my case, I always have `size(arr1) / size(arr2) = 2`.

   We replace the values in `arr1` from the index `1 * batch` and `3 * batch`.

   In most cases, I need to replace items in odd batches. The case for general batches is also needed.
2. Merge two vectors alternating indexes.

   A same question is raised in [How to merge 2 vectors alternating indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961897/how-to-merge-2-vectors-alternating-indexes), but is for `R` language.

   ```
   arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   arr2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
   //After merging arr1 and arr2:
   arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2, 2]
   ```

   `replace_copy_if` may work, but I don't know how to combine it with fancy iterators. Additionally, some blogs show that `replace_copy_if` is slower than `copy_if`.

Comment: In what format do you get the offsets for (1)? A vector of offsets `[1, 3]`?

Comment: I don't see how `replace_copy_if` (or any other `replace` algorithm) would be helpful here, as they always replace with a single value, not with different entries from another vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This operation scatters the values in `arr2` into `arr1`, so let's use `thrust::scatter`. The indices to which the values are scattered can be calculated with a `thrust::transform_iterator` from a `thrust::counting_iterator` (like `std::ranges::views::iota`). For the general case where the batch `indices` are given as another input `thrust::device_vector`, you can use

   ```cpp
   const auto indices_ptr = indices.data();

   const auto scatter_indices_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
       thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
       [batch, indices_ptr]
       __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
           const int batch_id = idx / batch;
           const int elem_id = idx % batch;
           return indices_ptr[batch_id] * batch + elem_id;
       });
   ```

   while in the specific case where you just want to scatter to the odd batches, you should rather use

   ```cpp
   const auto scatter_indices_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
       thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
       [batch]
       __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
           const int batch_id = idx / batch;
           const int elem_id = idx % batch;
           return (batch_id * 2 + 1) * batch + elem_id;
       });
   ```

   The `scatter` operation itself is easy:

   ```cpp
   thrust::scatter(
       arr2.cbegin(), arr2.cend(),
       scatter_indices_it,
       arr1.begin());
   ```
2. There are certainly multiple possible ways of doing this. The one that came to mind first for me was merging the two vectors with `thrust::merge_by_key`, where the keys are generated using a similar scheme as above for the scatter indices:

   ```cpp
   const auto merge_keys1_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
       thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
       [batch]
       __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
           const int batch_id = idx / batch;
           return batch_id * 2;
       });
   const auto merge_keys2_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
       thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
       [batch]
       __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
           const int batch_id = idx / batch;
           return batch_id * 2 + 1;
       });
   thrust::merge_by_key(
       merge_keys1_it, merge_keys1_it + arr1.size(),
       merge_keys2_it, merge_keys2_it + arr2.size(),
       arr1.cbegin(),
       arr2.cbegin(),
       thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
       arr3.begin());
   ```

   This works and is relatively elegant, but probably not ideal for performance due to the complexity of the merge algorithm and the regularity of the operation. A (probably) more performant ansatz would be creating a fancy iterator that takes care of the whole interleaving operation:

   ```cpp
   const auto arr1_ptr = arr1.data();
   const auto arr2_ptr = arr2.data();

   const auto batch_interleave_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
       thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
       [batch, arr1_ptr, arr2_ptr]
       __host__ __device__ (int idx) -> int {
           const int batch_id = idx / batch;
           const int batch_el = idx % batch;
           const int in_idx = (batch_id / 2) * batch + batch_el;
           const bool even_batch = (batch_id % 2 == 0);
           return even_batch ? arr1_ptr[in_idx] : arr2_ptr[in_idx];
       });
   ```

   This iterator can now be fed to the next algorithm in your pipeline for kernel fusion or used to initialize a new vector using the constructor which takes an `begin` and an `end` iterator. If the interleaved `arr3` is used (read from) multiple times in future it, you should probably put it into a new vector instead of reusing the iterator as the iterator doesn't allow for coalesced global memory access if `batch` isn't a multiple of warp size (32).

### Complete source code:

Due to the use of device lambdas, `nvcc` needs `-extended-lambda`. Since CUDA 12 it also needs `-rdc=true` for some reason.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <thrust/merge.h>

#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>

template <typename T>
void print(const thrust::device_vector<T> &vec) {
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(vec);
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it(std::cout, ", ");
    thrust::copy(h_vec.cbegin(), h_vec.cend(),
                 out_it);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void part1() {
    constexpr int h_arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    constexpr int h_arr2[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};
    constexpr int batch = 3;

    thrust::device_vector<int> arr1(std::cbegin(h_arr1), std::cend(h_arr1));
    thrust::device_vector<int> arr2(std::cbegin(h_arr2), std::cend(h_arr2));
    
    assert(arr1.size() == 2 * arr2.size());

#if 1
    // specialized version where arr2 is scattered to "uneven"
    // batches
    const auto scatter_indices_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        [batch]
        __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
            const int batch_id = idx / batch;
            const int elem_id = idx % batch;
            return (batch_id * 2 + 1) * batch + elem_id;
        });
#else
    // more general version where arr2 is scattered to batches given
    // in indices
    constexpr int h_indices[] = {1, 3};
    thrust::device_vector<int> indices(
        std::cbegin(h_indices), std::cend(h_indices));
    const auto indices_ptr = indices.data();

    const auto scatter_indices_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        [batch, indices_ptr]
        __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
            const int batch_id = idx / batch;
            const int elem_id = idx % batch;
            return indices_ptr[batch_id] * batch + elem_id;
        });
#endif
    
    thrust::scatter(
        arr2.cbegin(), arr2.cend(),
        scatter_indices_it,
        arr1.begin());

    print(arr1);
}

void part2() {
    constexpr int h_arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    constexpr int h_arr2[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};
    constexpr int batch = 3;

    thrust::device_vector<int> arr1(std::cbegin(h_arr1), std::cend(h_arr1));
    thrust::device_vector<int> arr2(std::cbegin(h_arr2), std::cend(h_arr2));
    const auto out_size = arr1.size() + arr2.size();

    assert(arr1.size() == arr2.size());

#if 1
    const auto arr1_ptr = arr1.data();
    const auto arr2_ptr = arr2.data();

    const auto batch_interleave_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        [batch, arr1_ptr, arr2_ptr]
        __host__ __device__ (int idx) -> int {
            const int batch_id = idx / batch;
            const int batch_el = idx % batch;
            const int in_idx = (batch_id / 2) * batch + batch_el;
            const bool even_batch = (batch_id % 2 == 0);
            return even_batch ? arr1_ptr[in_idx] : arr2_ptr[in_idx];
        });

    // only put into vector if really needed, better to feed the
    // iterator directly to the next operation for kernel fusion
    thrust::device_vector<int> arr3(
        batch_interleave_it, batch_interleave_it + out_size);
#else
    thrust::device_vector<int> arr3(out_size);

    const auto merge_keys1_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        [batch]
        __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
            const int batch_id = idx / batch;
            return batch_id * 2;
        });
    const auto merge_keys2_it = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        [batch]
        __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
            const int batch_id = idx / batch;
            return batch_id * 2 + 1;
        });
    
    thrust::merge_by_key(
        merge_keys1_it, merge_keys1_it + arr1.size(),
        merge_keys2_it, merge_keys2_it + arr2.size(),
        arr1.cbegin(),
        arr2.cbegin(),
        thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
        arr3.begin());
#endif

    print(arr3);
}

int main(void) {
    part1();
    part2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! For (2), merge using fancy iterator, I think the logic of calculating 'in_idx' should be modified, i.e., `in_idx = (batch_id / 2) * batch + batch_el` instead of `in_idx = batch_id / 2 + batch_el`. Otherwise, when test other batch size, the result is wrong (e.g., `batch=4`).     Another thing is that merge using keys is actually slower than using iterators. as you said. E.g., for `arr1.size=100000*16` and `batch=100000`, the former is `0.38ms` and the latter is `0.16ms`

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the correction! Shows the importance of testing multiple inputs ^^