# Removing repeated letters/alphabets

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Input : kdff455556tfkkkw

Output1 : kdf[2]45[4]6tfk[3]w

Hint: Repeated "alphnum" by the alphnum[No_Of_Repetition]

Comment: can you at least rephrase it in your own words

Answer (score 3):

```
s <- c('kdff455556tfkkkw','abc','abbccc');
sapply(strsplit(s,''),function(x) paste(with(rle(x),ifelse(lengths==1,values,paste0(values,'[',lengths,']'))),collapse=''));
## [1] "kdf[2]45[4]6tfk[3]w" "abc"                 "ab[2]c[3]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a roundabout regex approach:

```
require(stringr)
p <- "(([a-z0-9])\\2+)"
x <- str_split(s,p)
r <- sapply(str_extract_all(s,p),
       function(x)if (length(x))paste0(substr(x,1,1),"[",nchar(x),"]")else "")

mapply(function(x,r)paste0(
  c(x,r)[order(c(seq_along(x),seq_along(r)))]
,collapse=""),x,r)
# output for @bgoldst's input:
# [1] "kdf[2]45[4]6tfk[3]w" "abc"                 "ab[2]c[3]"
```

The last step is an interleaving trick [copied from @Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443987/1191259).

---

I wish my initial guess had worked:

```
sapply(s,function(x)gsub(p,paste0("\\2[",nchar("\\1"),"]"),x))
```

But it seems that `"\\1"` is is not evaluated inside `gsub`, and somehow always has two characters:

```
#      kdff455556tfkkkw                   abc                abbccc 
# "kdf[2]45[2]6tfk[2]w"                 "abc"           "ab[2]c[2]"
```