# R sequence automation

Tags: r

```
c(2:5,
1:1,
3:5,
1:2,
4:5,
1:3,
5:5,
1:4)
> 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4.
```

As one can see there is a pattern here. Starting at n=5 n-3:n, counting down and then followed by 1:n-4 and so on. My question is there any way to automate this using `seq()` and `rep()` in R?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could view this as a loop of some variable `d` from 3 to 0 where for each value `d` you add the following two vectors:

```
(n-d):n
1:(n-d-1)
```

Armed with this analysis, we can pretty easily perform this as a one-liner:

```
n <- 5
as.vector(sapply(3:0, function(d) c((n-d):n, 1:(n-d-1))))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```

Another way that would be a bit more efficient but in my opinion less understandable could use `outer` and modulo:

```
as.vector(outer(0:(n-1), 3:0, function(x, y) (x-y-1) %% n + 1))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
c(sapply(1:5, function(u) (1:5)[-u]))
#[1] 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Ah, great pattern matching on the output sequence -- this is definitely the simplest approach yet! Because the OP had used four groups of five I hadn't thought to look at the sequence as five groups of four.

Comment: fortunately we are reasonning in a commutative division ring :)

Answer (score 2):

**Interleaving lists.** You can use [@Arun's approach to interleaving two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443987/1191259):

```
a = lapply(2:5, function(x) x:5)
b = lapply(1:4, function(x) 1:x)

idx <- order(c(seq_along(a), seq_along(b)))
unlist(c(a,b)[idx])
# [1] 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```

---

**Matrix tricks.** Alternately, try some matrix-index trickery:

```
n = 5
m = matrix(,n,n-1)
v = c( col(m) + row(m) ) %% n

v + n*!v
# [1] 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on josilber's answer (I thought of it as a repeating circular shift):

```
n=5
d=4
as.vector(sapply(seq(d),function(x, y) c(tail(y, -x), head(y, x)), y=seq(n)))
[1] 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```