# Inserting a table object in a data.frame cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I am calculating a table for each row of a data.frame `df`.
I would like to assign these tables as values of a new column of my database (so that each row has one table assigned).
But trying to put a table into a data.frame only results in using the first value of the table.

```
df <- data.frame(values = c("row 1","row 2", "row 3"))

v_row_1 <- c("one", "one", "two", "three", "three")
t_row_1 <- table(v_row_1)

df[1, "tables"] <- t_row_1

Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = list(values = c(1, 2, 3),  :
provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
```

I think that one solution would be to convert my table `t` into a string object and then assing this object to the cell in my dataframe. But if I use `paste(toString(t))` to do this I lose the table names (and I still can't get this thing into a data.frame cell).

My desidered output would roughtly look like:

```
values             tables
row 1              one 2 three 2 two 1
row 2              ...
row 3              ...
```

I do not mind if the tables are converted in a linear string as long as they are readable.

Comment: Can you post your desired output too?

Comment: This "works": `df[1,"tables"] <- list(list(t))`

Comment: @Frank I still do not get the table names but only their values: `c(2, 2, 1)`. I woul like to get: `one 2 three 2 two 1`.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Looking for a workaround.

Comment: @Frank, it's all there, just not printed. Is a workaround really needed? The data structure that you provide is going to be better than a single string (unless you try to save as a CSV or something....)

Comment: @Ananda I actually need to human-read it when exported in a csv.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yeah, I suspect the OP just wants this for browsing the data rather than further analysis.

Comment: @Frank, then how about `toString(sprintf("%s (%d)", names(t), t))`.

Comment: Are you looking for `do.call(paste,as.data.frame(t_row_1))`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Oh, that's a really good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Thanks to @AnandaMahto) You can use

```
df[1, "tables"] <- toString(sprintf("%s (%d)", names(t), t))

#   values              tables
# 1      1 one 2 three 2 two 1
# 2      2                  NA
# 3      3                  NA
```

Here's another way to get the string result, [borrowed from @Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443987/1191259)'s trick for interleaving lists:

```
df[1, "tables"] <- 
  paste( c(names(t), t)[order(c(seq_along(t), seq_along(t)))], collapse = " " )
```

---

*Comments.*

`t` is the matrix transpose function, so it might get confusing if you reuse it.

If you want to store the full table object, you can do

```
df[1,"tables"] <- list(list(t))
```

The downside is that when viewing `df`, the names of table elements will not be visible.

Comment: This interleaving thing is probably overkill, in light of Ananda's much simpler `sprintf` approach.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Oh, good catch; it seems it does not. Thanks for adding your answer. I've edited to put it at the top, since it's the best way to go.