# How to interleave vectors in R according to a position indicator

Tags: r

Is there some way to perform a controlled interleave of vectors in R? That is, suppose I have multiple vectors `v1`, `v2`, `v3` containing values and a vector of positions, something like this:

```
v1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
v2 <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
v3 <- c("x", "y", "z")
pos <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1)
```

It is always the case that the number of `1`s in `pos` is equal to the number of elements in `v1` and so on, i.e. `all.equal(c(length(v1), length(v2), length(v3)), as.vector(table(pos)))` is `TRUE`.

What I'd like is some way to interleave the vectors according to the values in `pos`, i.e. create a vector `i <- c(v1[1], v1[2], v2[1], v3[1], v2[2], v2[3], v3[2], v2[4], v1[3], v3[3], v2[5], v1[4])` where the entry corresponding to the n-th appearance of `1` in `pos` is the n-th element of `v1`, and likewise for `v2`, `v3`, ...

I've tried to hack it together with a `for` loop, like so:

```
v <- list(v1, v2, v3)
for (p in 1:length(pos)) {
    ind <- pos[1:p] == pos[p]
    i[p] <- v[[pos[p]]][cumsum(ind)[p]]
}
i
#> [1] "a" "b" "1" "x" "2" "3" "y" "4" "c" "z" "5" "d"
```

But while this *seems* to get the job done, it's an awfully messy solution, and I'm hoping there's something a bit more elegant and time efficient for my real situation where `pos` has millions of entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of iterating over positions, you can iterate over vectors:

```
i = character(length(pos))
for (p in 1:length(v)) i[ pos == p ] <- v[[p]]
#  "a" "b" "1" "x" "2" "3" "y" "4" "c" "z" "5" "d"
```

The loop can also be avoided here:

```
i = character(length(pos))
i[ order(pos) ] <- c(v1,v2,v3)
# "a" "b" "1" "x" "2" "3" "y" "4" "c" "z" "5" "d"
```

For reference, I looked at [this other nice question on interleaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443260/interleave-lists-in-r).

Comment: This is the smartest answer I've seen in awhile. Very nice