# Append logical operators in between character vectors

Tags: r

I have a big character vector, for example, I take only three elements

```
vec <- c("first", "second", "third")
```

and I have logical vector

```
logVec <- c("Or", "And")
```

I want output as:

```
"first Or second And third"
```

I tried it using `paste0`, but it takes for loop to traverse every pair and appending logical vector sequentially. Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: `paste(c(vec, logVec)[ order(c(seq_along(vec), seq_along(logVec))) ], collapse = " ")` Borrowed this from Arun's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16443987

Comment: or `paste(head(c(t(matrix(c(vec, logVec), length(vec)))), -1), collapse = ' ')`

Comment: Great and simple. Thanks both of u