# Why there appear three NA's at the end?

Tags: r

I was trying to write an `interleave()` function for two vectors of arbitrary length.

For equal-length vectors, 
I found in the [internet](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2019/01/29/interleaving-vectors-and-matrices-part-1/):

```
.interleave <- function(vec1, vec2) {
  # cuts away longer
  res <- rbind(vec1, vec2)
  attributes(res) <- NULL
  res
}
# c(rbind(vec1, vec2)) is shorter code, but 
# is 3x slower according to the blog in the link
```

So for arbitrary length, I thought, I measure the lengths first and attach the rest of the longer vector.

```
interleave <- function(vec1, vec2) {
  vec1_len <- length(vec1)
  vec2_len <- length(vec2)
  min_len  <- min(vec1_len, vec2_len)
  if (vec1_len == vec2_len) {
    .interleave(vec1, vec2)
  } else {
    c(.interleave(vec1[1:min_len], vec2[1:min_len]),
      if (vec1_len > vec2_len) { 
        vec1[min_len+1:vec1_len]
      } else {
        vec2[min_len+1:vec2_len]
      })  
  }
} # strangely 3 NA's at end if unequal length
```

But now comes the strange thing:

```
interleave(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
## [1]  1  4  2  5  3  6  7  8  9 NA NA NA

interleave(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
## [1] 1 4 2 5 3 6 

interleave(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5))
## [1]  1  4  2  5  3 NA NA

interleave(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
## [1]  1  4  2  5  3  6  7  8  9 10 11 NA NA NA
interleave(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), c( 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
## [1]  1  7  2  8  3  9  4 10  5 11  6 NA NA NA NA NA
```

From where do the `NA`s come from?
Remark: I see the pattern that the number of attached `NA`s
is the number of elements in the shorter vector ...

How to generate a version without `NA`s?

**Solution**

Sorry, I found it out myself.
Problem was the subsetting of the rest-vector.
I forgot some parantheses.

```
interleave <- function(vec1, vec2) {
  vec1_len <- length(vec1)
  vec2_len <- length(vec2)
  min_len  <- min(vec1_len, vec2_len)
  if (vec1_len == vec2_len) {
    .interleave(vec1, vec2)
  } else {
    c(.interleave(vec1[1:min_len], vec2[1:min_len]),
      if (vec1_len > vec2_len) { 
        vec1[(min_len+1):vec1_len] # parantheses!
      } else {
        vec2[(min_len+1):vec2_len] # parantheses!
      })  
  }
} # no NA's any more!
```

**Slightly shorter**

```
interleave <- function(vec1, vec2) {
  vec1_len <- length(vec1)
  vec2_len <- length(vec2)
  min_len  <- min(vec1_len, vec2_len)
  if (vec1_len == vec2_len) {
    .interleave(vec1, vec2)
  } else {
    c(.interleave(vec1[1:min_len], vec2[1:min_len]),
      if (vec1_len > vec2_len) {
        vec1[(min_len+1):vec1_len]
      } else {
        vec2[(min_len+1):vec2_len]
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A general function:

```
interleave <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    len <- max(lengths(l))
    l <- lapply(l, function(x) `length<-`(x, len))
    res <- na.omit(c(do.call(rbind, l)))
    attributes(res) <- NULL
    res
}

interleave(1:9, seq(10,40,10), seq(100,500,100))
#[1]   1  10 100   2  20 200   3  30 300   4  40 400   5 500   6   7   8   9
```

and also generalizing [Interleave lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443260/interleave-lists-in-r/16443987#16443987)

```
interleave <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    idx <- order(unlist(lapply(l, function(x) seq_along(x))))
    unlist(l)[idx]
}
```

Comment: thanks. This kind I did, too. But I am trying to avoid lists. Because lists in R are very slow. My `interleave()` is just a helper function for a `strsplit()` equivalent I want to write, because `strsplit()` uses lists inside and therefore is terribly slow. And I am trying to write a method to split strings using mainly the `substr()` and `gregexpr()`. Because this is muuch faster. I know that such function exists in tidyverse already. But I wanted to write my own for learning purposes.